# Rewrite dynamic url in file .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, dynamic, url-rewriting

Here is a dynamic url download file at my site:

```
Eg: mywebsite/shortUrl?download_token=xxxxxxx
```

Now I want to rewrite the url to:

```
Eg: mywebsite/shortUrl/download/xxxxxxx
```

how to rewrite?

Comment: Hey! Please help me!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/download/([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$ $1?download_token=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Sorry, it looks like you've misunderstood! The 'shortURL' above is a static string that changes with each file. Can you give me another code that is more suitable?

Comment: @TầnQuảng Corrected

Comment: @TầnQuảng Wrote a more concise version

Comment: It does not seem wrong...
You can understand like this:
[link](Eg: http://my-domain/a-short-string-change-by-file?download_token=a crypt token change every time download)
Now I want to rewrite it to:
[link](Eg: http://my domain/a-short-string-change-by-file/download(virtual)/a crypt token change every time download)

Comment: use this pattern ([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+) to change the address of the link. On the right side, use $1, $2, $n.

Comment: Hi! I using crypt function! The first before "?download_token=" always is "$1$"... (?download_token=$1$...)! Please help me, it's hard problem! :(

Comment: And I used RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/download/([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$ $1?download_token=$2 [L] get website many redirect! Please help me! :(

Comment: No, this is not correct: $1, $2 - variables. For example, you must have at the input such an address: your.site/2b38c8a?download_token=f3439e32

Comment: output: your.site/2b38c8a/download/f3439e32

Comment: Eg: Input: (cdn or no cdn).your.site/2ajh368(change by file)?download_token=$1$3.ewg/psjeh.yhwhotw== (token dynamic use crypt + base64 function) Now, I want output: (cdn or no cdn).your.site/f(dir virtual)/dl(dir virtual)/2ajh368(change by file)/download(dir virtual)/$1$3.ewg/psjeh.yhwhotw==(token dynamic use crypt + base64 function)

Comment: Can you complete the rewrite?

Comment: And I have to change the input url structure in file php the same as the output url in .htaccess?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to learn rewrite url so I still very poor! Please help me! (°////°)

Comment: okay) use this: `RewriteRule ^f/dl/([a-z0-9]+)/download/([a-z0-9]+)/psjeh.yhwhotw==([a-z0-9]+)$ $1?download_token=$2/psjeh.yhwhotw==$3 [L]` sorry, i didn't understand this part `$1$3.ewg`. i made it as a variable $2. try not to use the URL address of symbols `$`. this symbol is used as a regular expression operator

Comment: If this part `$1$3.ewg` is treated as a string `S1S3.ewg`. use this code: `RewriteRule ^f/dl/([a-z0-9]+)/download/S1S3.ewg/psjeh.yhwhotw==([a-z0‌​-9]+)$ $1?download_token=S1S3.ewg/psjeh.yhwhotw==$2 [L]` Here I replaced the symbol $ by S

Comment: As I understand it, download token goes after this expression `download_token=S1S3.ewg/psjeh.yhwhotw==(your token)` Otherwise, if this part `S1S3.ewg/psjeh.yhwhotw==` is a changing download token, use this code: `RewriteRule ^f/dl/([a-z0-9]+)/download/([a-z0‌​-‌​9\/\.\$\=]+)$ $1?download_token=$2 [L]`. In this case, you can use symbols $. In this example, you can use english letters, numbers and symbols (. \ =) in your token

Comment: S1S3.ewg/psjeh.yhwhotw== is example token!

Comment: So full rewrite is: RewriteRule ^f/dl/([a-z0-9]+)/download/([a-z0‌​-‌​9]+)$ $1([a-z0-9]+)?download_token=$2 [L]

Comment: I have to change the input url structure in file php the same as the output url in .htaccess?

Comment: no, use this code in .htaccess:  `RewriteRule ^f/dl/([a-z0-9]+)/download/([a-z0‌​-‌​9\/\.\$\=]+)$ $1?download_token=$2 [L]`. in PHP-file you need use a structure: `$1?download_token=$2`, where $1 - change by file and $2 - current download token. or use format: `index.php?file=$1&download_token=$2` (htaccess `RewriteRule ^f/dl/([a-z0-9]+)/download/([a-z0‌​-‌​9\/\.\$\=]+)$ index.php?file=$1&download_token=$2 [L]`)

Comment: So that means I just add to the .htaccess file and the php file stays the same old structure and when download any file it will migrate to the same structure in the .htaccess file?

Comment: Before rewriting an URL, you need to make sure that your page is opened at `index.php?file=$1&download_token=$2`, $1, $2 - variables

Comment: For example, in the root url, I have added some variables, then in .htaccess I will have to add that variable.
Example:
Url root: ...?download_token=dynamic token&variable-1=dynamic token&variable-2=dynamic token...
Then in the .htaccess file I would also have to add:
....?download_token=$2&variable-1=$3&variable-2=$4...
Right?

Comment: If my root url has those variables but in the .htaccess file I just to come ...?download_token and remove the variable part going (variable-1,2,..), it's right?

Comment: Please rewrite the url for me this link! Root url: my.site/folder/id folder (only numbers)/directory name (including Latin characters, accented Vietnamese characters, Chinese characters, ....)?sharekey=one The token consists of characters a-z A-Z 0-9 . ,; :! - _      The link wants to rewrite to: my.site/folder/id directory (numbers only)/directory names (including Latin characters, accented Vietnamese letters, Chinese characters, ....)/k/a token segment consisting of AZ AZ characters 0-9. ,; :! - _/share/views

Comment: That is, replaced "?sharekey=" with "/k/".